# Como fazer scroll horizontal no tumblr?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá! Já tentei muitos tutoriais, mas não consigo nada. O tema de base que estou a tentar alterar é o [seguinte](http://pastebin.com/b80miuhb).

Escrever o seguinte não faz com que o scroll horizontal acontece, só bloqueia o vertical:

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Exemplo no JsFiddle pode ser [visto aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/bk5qqf65/#&togetherjs=QdEdJIJGF5).
O blog [é este.](http://rlxs.tumblr.com/)

Comment: Podes criar um jsFiddle com um exemplo do teu problema?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bk5qqf65/#&togetherjs=QdEdJIJGF5

O blog é este http://rlxs.tumblr.com/